# How to programmatically load a component to a variable to be used in anothe component?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 4 project. I'm writing a generic calendar component that can be used in multiple places throughout. However, I'd like to be able to have the option to set a component for the calendar table's cell content.

Is there a way to programmatically load a component as a var in the .component.ts file to be used in the other .html file?

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
<app-calendar
    contentControl="app-detailed-text-calendar-day">
</app-calendar>

<app-calendar
    contentControl="app-graphical-calendar-day">
</app-calendar>
```

Is this possible? What's the ideal pattern to use?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just put the component inside the table's cell, and then  use `ngIf` when you want to show it?

Comment: @tic is correct. If you have a limited number of options, take an input as to which component you want to show in the cell and use *ngIf. If you need it to be different everytime, use transclusion <ng-content></ng-content>. Either of these, based on your need should solve your issue.

Comment: I have more options than just the two examples. Also, each will have unique arguments/inputs.